# How to get the function return result from case statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql :

```sql
    select case funcation_b(t.name) 
               when funcation_b(t.name) is null then null
               else funcation_b(t.name)
             end as result
     from table_a t;
```

I want the funcation_b(t.name)  can be instesd by a symbol or something esle.

what I want is avoid call the funcation more than once,I want to know if there is a way to make it .
 by the way,   I think,I can not use  like this :

```sql
    select  funcation_b(t.name)  temp
       case  
         when temp is null then null
         else temp
      end as result
     from table_a t;
```

because the sql below is a part of a  union all sql .

Comment: How is this code different from `select function_b(t.name) as result`?

Comment: Well, the syntax error is a difference...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `CASE` doesn't make much sense as it is equal to

```
select funcation_b(t.name) result
from table_a t;
```

as it'll display `NULL` if the function returns `NULL`.

---

If you insist, then

```
select case when funcation_b(t.name) is null then null
            else funcation_b(t.name)
       end as result
 from table_a t;
```

---

**[EDIT]**

After you edited the question, saying that you want to call the function only once: the first suggestion (omit CASE completely) does that.

Otherwise, you could use CTE (common table expression) a.k.a. WITH factoring clause, such as

```
with temp as
  (select t.name,
          funcation_b(t.name) result
   from table_a t
  )
-- and now do whatever you want, such as
select result,
       count(*)
from temp
group by result;
```

Comment: I edited my answer after reading what you posted afterwards. Have a look, please.